# PHP OOP approach difficultiues

Tags: php, oop

**Please see edit below**

<strike>I'm trying to dive into OOP development in PHP and i'm really starting to develop a headache or ulcer. I just can't wrap my head around it, parts seem too illogical to me, and i have no clue where to start and it really frustrates me because i believe it's worth the effort to try to learn it and it provides my a better overview about my code.</strike>

Yesterday i spent the whole day searching for practical examples and explanational articles on the internet, but now i have the feeling that only confuses me more. I need some practical tips, not examples like

```
class person {
     var $name;
     function set_name($new_name) {
          $this->name = $new_name;
     }
     function get_name() {
          return $this->name;
     }
}
$stefan = new person();
$jimmy = new person;
```

$stefan->set_name("Stefan");
$jimmy->set_name("Jimmy");

echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
echo "Jimmy's full name: " . $jimmy->get_name();

Examples like this makes me question why i shouldn't (because it's all defined in the same page) just do

```
$name = "Stefan"; 
echo "Stefan's full name: ".$name;
```

Shorter (less code) and more obvious if you ask me?

Nou to my project.

The thing i'm trying to make is a simple portfolio website. Herefore i only need 4 pages, a *home page*, *information* page, a page about *my work* and a *contact* form. I use three tables `clients`, `content` and `media` which i want to use on the *my work* page.

I was thinking about my structure and came up (in my head, no clue how to achieve it) with something like

```
class Database{}
class Content extends Database{}
     function showMenu(){}
     function showContent{}
class Clients extends Database{}
     function showClientList{}
     function showClientDetails{}
class Media extends Database{}
```

I already made a database class that establishes a database connection with a public method `query($qry)`. I started with the `Content` class and it looks like this at the moment:

```
class Content extends Database {
    public function topMenu($page){
        $db = new Database();
        $db->connect();
        $db->query("SELECT m_link, m_title, m_accesskey FROM menu WHERE m_type = 'top'"); 
        $res = $db->getResult();
        foreach($res AS $show){
            if($page == $show['m_link']){
                echo("<li id="active">$show['m_title']."</li>\n");
            }else{
                echo("<li>$show['m_title']."</li>\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make any sense at all by the way?

On my index.php i have the following lines to display the menu (which work fine) `$content = new Content(); $content->topMenu($_aGET[0]);`

The point where i'm loosing it is the way top display either the *client list* or the *client details*, which depends on the variable `$_aGET[0]` (which holds the url)

Suppose i want to display the client details, herefore i need records from all three the tables, so normally i would use a couple of join's, like so

```
$query = "
    SELECT cl.c_id, cl.c_client, cl.c_client_desc, ncc.clco_cl_id, ncc.clco_co_id, co.c_content, ncm.clme_me_id, ncm.clme_cl_id, GROUP_CONCAT(me.m_link) AS images_link
    FROM clienten AS cl
    LEFT JOIN norm_cl_co_rel AS ncc ON cl.c_id = ncc.clco_cl_id
    LEFT JOIN content AS co ON ncc.clco_co_id = co.c_id
    LEFT JOIN norm_cl_me_rel AS ncm ON cl.c_id = ncm.clme_cl_id
    LEFT JOIN media AS me ON me.m_id = ncm.clme_me_id
    WHERE cl.c_client = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_aGET[1])."'
    AND cl.c_language_id = '"._LANGUAGE."' 
    AND cl.c_active = '1'
";
```

But as far is i understand the OOP thoughts, i should have a method for each tables defined in a class (right?) But how am i going to join these?

Or does my 'story' looks something like: 'Dude, just drop it and stick with procedural coding'?

**EDIT:**

Ok, after Fluffeh's post i used his example and modified it a bit to test it. The problem is that i do get some output, but not the desired. My output is like below

```
ID: CompanyName
C
Desc: C
Media:
: 
: 
: 
: 
:
```

while i should get (values are in the database):

```
ID: CompanyName
CompanyName
Desc: CompanyName is a company
Media:
: Image 1
: Image 2
: Image 3
: Image 4
: Image 5
```

My code looks like so:

```
class media{
    public $type;
    public $title;
    public $image;
    public $desc;
}

class client{
    public $name;
    public $desc;
}

class clientDetails{

    private $clientID;
    public $clientName;
    public $clientDesc;
    public $clientMedia = array();
    public $clientMediaFiles = 0;

    public function __construct($myID){
        $this->clientID = $myID;
    }

    public function getMyDetails(){

        $db = new Database();
        $db->connect();
        $db->query("
            SELECT c_client, c_client_desc 
            FROM clienten 
            WHERE c_client = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->clientID)."'
        ");
        foreach($db->getResult() as $client){
            $this->name = $client['c_client'];
            $this->desc = $client['c_client_desc'];
        }

        $db = new Database();
        $db->connect();
        $db->query("
            SELECT ncm.clme_me_id, ncm.clme_cl_id, cl.c_id, me.m_id, me.m_type, me.m_title, me.m_desc, me.m_link
            FROM norm_cl_me_rel AS ncm
            LEFT JOIN clienten AS cl ON cl.c_id = ncm.clme_cl_id
            LEFT JOIN media AS me ON me.m_id = ncm.clme_me_id
            WHERE me.m_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
        ");
        foreach($db->getResult() as $media){
            $this->clientMedia[$i]= new media();
            $this->clientMedia[$i]->type = $media['m_type'];
            $this->clientMedia[$i]->title = $media['m_title'];
            $this->clientMedia[$i]->image = $media['m_image'];
            $this->clientMedia[$i]->desc = $media['m_desc'];
            $this->clientMediaFiles++;
        }
    }

    public function displayMyResults(){
        echo "ID: $this->clientID";
        echo "&lt;div>&lt;h3>".$this->name."&lt;/h3>";
        echo "Desc: ".$this->desc."&lt;br>";
        echo "Media:&lt;br>";
        for($i=0;$i<$this->clientMediaFiles;$i++){
            echo $this->clientMedia[$i]->title." : ".$this->clientMedia[$i]->desc."&lt;br>";
        }
        echo "&lt;/div>";
    }

}
```

Comment: How much do you know about OOP generally? If the answer is "nothing/not alot", I would suggest you go learn it in a different (better) language first - learning OOP in PHP will teach you some very bad habits and will leave some very important areas (e.g. generics) out completely. I usually suggest people start in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) because it's a proper OOP language that's still quite high level and doesn't have you messing about with memory pointers, others can (and probably will) disagree. PHP is *not* an OOP language. It's a scripting language with OOP features.

Comment: Also, once you learn the basics of OO you will find that there are libraries/frameworks out there that do a lot of / all the heavy lifting with regard to fetching details out of the database. Things like Symfony and the Zend Framework.

Comment: Two notes: a) Don't start with your own database encapsulation when learning oop; you _will_ do it wrong and it will ruin your whole project, you learn next to nothing and you will get frustrated -> use an existing one. b) `Content extends Database` : Content `is a` Database? Probably not... What sources do you use to learn oop ?

Comment: @Maurice Okay, added some code to my comment. Please let me know if you can follow this or if I need to keep going. You are my priority project for this evening :)

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but those little examples of OOP like the one in the beginning of your question rarely give a proper situation in which OOP is useful. If you were actually writing code that simple, OOP would of course be excessive. But stick with it, and it will become worth it very quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep going with OOP. Once you get it, you will never want to go back to pesky, troublesome, nasty, horrible, rabid procedural code.

To take the example of this: *Suppose i want to display the client details, herefore i need records from all three the tables, so normally i would use a couple of join's, like so...*

This is a great example that can be used to show you how useful OOP can be.

Create a class for *ClientDetails*

- Create a constructor within it that accepts the clientID as an argument.
- Inside this constructor, have it run the code and populate it's internal variables with the data that is returned by the query.
- Create a function that outputs the data that is returned into a nice format.
- Now create it from your main code and have it display it's details

Suddenly you have a few lines of code in a class, but can display your data perfectly in 2 lines of code.

I will be adding some example code shortly, will see if I can rummage some of my classes for a demo.

Edit: Dammit, no rummaging of old classes, much too detailed for this, but I wrote some code for an example:

```
<?php

class clientContact
{
    public $name;
    public $phone;
}

class clientDetails
{
    private $clientID;      //only this class can access this variable.
    public $clientName;     // Anything can change these.
    public $clientPhone;
    public $additionalContacts= array();
    public $associates=0;

    public function __construct($myID)
    // This is a magic function that is called every time we make a new object of this class.
    {
        $this->$clientID=$myID;
    }

    public function getMyDetails()
    // This function will query the database to get it's information properly
    // and populate itself with everything it needs. You could do this as part
    // of the __construct() call, but I didn't want to do TOO much code.
    {
        $sql="select clientName, clientPhone from clients where clientID=".$this->clientID.";";
        // skipping over full SQl bits...
        foreach($stmt as $clientContact)
        {
            $this->clientName=$clientContact->clientName;
            $this->clientPhone=$clientContact->clientPhone;
        }

        $sql="select clientName, clientPhone from associates where assocID=".$this->clientID.";";
        // skipping over full SQl bits...
        foreach($stmt as $clientContact)
        {
            $this->additionalContacts[$i]= new clientContact();
            $this->additionalContacts[$i]->name=$clientContact->name;
            $this->additionalContacts[$i]->phone=$clientContact->phone;
            $this->associates++;
        }

    }

    public function displayMyResults()
    // This function will simply display everything it has in a nicely format
    {
        echo "<div><h3>".$this->clientName."</h3>";
        echo "My contact phone number is :".$this->phone."<br>";
        echo "My associates are:<br>";
        for($i=0;$i<$this-associates;$i++)
        {
            echo $this->additionalContacts[$i]->name." : ".$this->additionalContacts[$i]->phone."<br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
}

?>
```

Good god, that's long and horrible right?

Not really. Here is why.

Sure, there is a bit of code in the class, but now, you can do the following on your main page:

```
<?php 

    $someArray=array(36, 25, 76); 
    // This could be from a query, or a form, or anything else

    for($i=0;$i<count($someArray);$i++)
    {
        $currentContact= new clientDetails($someArray[$i]);
        // This is how we create the object.

        $currentContact->getMyDetails();
        // This now tells the object to get it's own data

        $currentContact->displayMyResults();
        // This now displays the data in the object to the page.
        echo "<hr>";
        unset($currentContact);
    }
?>
```

And with that TINY snippet of code, you have just displayed all the contacts, formatted as you want and you just perfectly displayed all the contacts exactly how you wanted them.

Now imagine that instead of just one little example like this, you use these sort of objects for ALL your content. A post on a forum? One object. A complex calculation for a business KPI? One Object that can get all of the data it has, then calculate a prediction, display the result in a graph and email it to the users that need it.

OOP can have a steep learning curve when you come from a background of HTML and PHP script which executes from top to bottom, but when you start getting the hang of it, you will wish you had learned it from the start.

Edit:

You don't seem to have the column `m_image` in your query:

```
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();
    $db->query("
        SELECT cl.c_id, ncm.clme_me_id, ncm.clme_cl_id, me.m_type, me.m_title, me.m_desc, me.m_link, m_image
        FROM clienten AS cl
        LEFT JOIN norm_cl_me_rel AS ncm ON cl.c_id = ncm.clme_cl_id
        LEFT JOIN media AS me ON me.m_id = ncm.clme_me_id
        WHERE me.m_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
    ");
    foreach($db->getResult() as $media){
        $this->clientMedia[$i]= new media();
        $this->clientMedia[$i]->type = $media['m_type'];
        $this->clientMedia[$i]->title = $media['m_title'];
        $this->clientMedia[$i]->image = $media['m_image'];
        $this->clientMedia[$i]->desc = $media['m_desc'];
        $this->clientMediaFiles++;
    }
```

Edit 2: I am not 100% sure, but it might be the field names being returned. Try replaceing the query with this:

```
SELECT cl.c_id as c_id, ncm.clme_me_id as clme_me_id, ncm.clme_cl_id as clme_cl_id, me.m_type as m_type, me.m_title as m_title, me.m_desc as m_desc, me. as m_link
FROM clienten AS cl
LEFT JOIN norm_cl_me_rel AS ncm ON cl.c_id = ncm.clme_cl_id
LEFT JOIN media AS me ON me.m_id = ncm.clme_me_id
WHERE me.m_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: This is all written and untested, so please feel free to edit if there are any typos in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help and excuses for the late reply but had a busy week. Seems logic somewhere, but still i don't get it working, see the edit in my post. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for helping but unfortunately still the same output :(

Comment: @Maurice Dammit thought it might have been a simple one :) Can you post the output of the query as an example? Also, you don't need to redeclare `$db = new Database();` unless you `unset($db);` or `$db=null;`

Comment: @Maurice Can you try to comment out the second set of `$db = new Database();` and `$db->connect();` and see if that makes a difference? For some reason, I think that the second foreach loop isn't being entered at all. That or drop a `echo 'Inside second foreach loop.';` inside it to verify that it is indeed iterating a result.

Comment: Well, when i remove the second <code>$db = new Database();</code> and <code>$db->connect();</code> the output is still only the first letter of the string but at the media part i get two more <code>:</code> signs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15113/discussion-between-maurice-and-fluffeh)

Comment: Fluffeh, you just taught me OOP in less than 1 minute. thank you for this post.

Comment: @r3wt Not a problem at all. It's one of those funny things that suddenly just clicks and that's it, there's no going back.

Comment: @Fluffeh Is it OK to have mySQL queries inside domain objects? I mean does it violate any OOP or multi-tier concept? Usually I make a different namespace for Database Access Layer having reference of my Domain Models in there and write all my queries and return objects or array of objects to my business layers which also has the domain model reference and from there I send objects to my presentation layer. So the references of my Domain objects travels from layer to layer.

Answer (score 0):

When I learned OOP on Java, they told me to think of each Object type as a **new variable type**. Meaning, if you have a class `Person` (P.S. it's cosindered good naming convention to uppercase the first letter in a class name), an object holding a `Person` object can be considered *of type `Person`*.

The best example I can give you was when I was making an **[IRC Bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat_bot)**. The Bot was required to keep track of `User`s, `Channel`s, and `Server`s. The IRC protocol is based *entirely* on strings.

While I could work with strings, that would greatly increase the complexity of my application, as well as code readability. Instead, I chose to convert that data into `Channel`, `User` and `Server` objects, which has methods to interact with the IRC server.

For example:

```
/**
 * Add $user to $channel.
 * @param Channel $channel
 * @param User    $user
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function addUser(Channel $channel, User $user) {
    if (!isset($this->chanList[$channel->name])) {          #Channel is not on channel list
        throw new Exception("You are not on that channel");
    }
    if (!isset($this->userList[$user->nick])) {             #User is not on global user list (New user)
        $this->userList[$user->nick] = $user;               #Add user to list
    }
    $this->chanList[$channel->name]->addUser($user);        #Add the user to the channel user list
}
```

That is called whenever a user joins a channel. This allows the `Bot` object to keep track of users and in what channels they are on. The code does some validation, and then adds the `User` object to the `Channel` object.

Now imagine if you had to use just strings, you'd have to parse each line from the IRC protocol, extract the required data, and manipulate some very large arrays. Eventually, you'd have one big mess, instead of keeping things nice and organized.

Answer (score -1):

So OOP is good approach, if is picked up with for example MVC and Front Controller patterns. But if you want only simple site with 4 pages, you can really use procedural code, no problem. If you know drupal, it is in 90% procedural code.

But...

```
$db = new Database();
        $db->connect();
```

Creating db object and connecting in each method isn't good idea. Much better is share across the script only one db con object. You can use singleton pattern and do somethig like this.

```
class Database extends PDO {

  private static db = null;

  private function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(/* here get some conf data*/);    
  }

  public static getDb() {
    if(!self::db) self::db = new self();
    return self::db;
  }

  /* here you can add your custom methods like loadMenu etc. */
}
```

Better can be too decouple logic view layer, see extract php function, which add all elements of array to actual symbols table (key is name of that variable and value is value).
With extract function you can do nice view layer, which decouple logic from view.
Something like:

```
define('TEMPLATE_DIR', __DIR__ . '/templates');

function render($template, $variables) {
  extract($variables);
  require TEMPLATE_DIR . "/$template.tpl.php"; 
}

$variables = array('menu_links' => Database::getDb()->getMenu());

render('menu', $variables);
```

In your menu.tpl.php:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($menu_links as $link) : ?>
  <li><a href="<?= $link['href'] ?>"><?= $link['title'] ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: The smaller the project, the easier it is to implement an OOP approach, so I don't see that as a good reason not to use procedural methods instead. It's also much easier to learn OOP on smaller projects, so if that's what the OP is trying to do, I see no reason to discourage him.

Answer (score -2):

PHP OOP often boils down to a good MVC (model view controler) conecpt and implementation.

As stated earlier, you often don't need to OOP with PHP since its shooting nuklear nukes into tin cans instead of baseballs... because websites tend to be MVCd by its pages itself and redundant code does not hurt anyone there really ( as long as you dont have a messing security in database/sessions/forms)

A good understandable example on PHP MVC is http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

First part is very understandable and the second part ( linked at the end of #1) is a bit confusing since the autor renamed some classes and did not explain them to the full extend.

But having a look into the code supplied in zip files already gives you a good idea.